# find common node and uncommone node with different value once using XSLT from xml

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <SEGMEM>
      <FIELD>
        <Entry type="Field">
          <MemoryVariable>x</MemoryVariable>
          <Variable>x(v9)</Variable>
          <offset>
            <lowerBound>0</lowerBound>
            <upperBound>31</upperBound>
          </offset>
        </Entry>
        <Entry type="Field">
          <MemoryVariable>LE</MemoryVariable>
          <Variable>LE(v10)</Variable>
          <offset>
            <lowerBound>0</lowerBound>
            <upperBound>0</upperBound>
          </offset>
        </Entry>
     </FIELD>
    <CONGRUENCES>
        <Entry type="congruence">
          <Variable>v6</Variable>
          <Value>
            <multiplier>0</multiplier>
            <offset>1</offset>
          </Value>
        </Entry>
        <Entry type="congruence">
          <Variable>x(v9)</Variable>
          <Value>
            <multiplier>1</multiplier>
            <offset>0</offset>
          </Value>
        </Entry>
      </CONGRUENCES>
    </SEGMEM>
```

I have XML like above. I need to search element of variable which are common in  `<Entry type="Field">` and in `<Entry type="congruence">` or not. variable will be displayed only once.

Output should be like following:

```
<table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>MemoryVariable</th>
        <th>Variable</th>
        <th>lowerbound/upperbound</th>
        <th>multiplier/offset</th>
      </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>x</td>      <!-- memory variable -->
         <td>x(v9)</td>  <!-- x(v9) is the in file and congruence entry -->
         <td>[0,31]</td> <!-- lowerbound and upperbound -->
         <td>[1,0]</td>  <!-- <multiplier>1</multiplier> <offset>0</offset> -->
       </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>LE</td>     <!-- memory variable again -->
         <td>LE(v10)</td><!-- LE(v10) is the in file and not in congruence entry -->
         <td>[0,0]</td>  <!-- lowerbound and upperbound -->
         <td>null</td>   <!-- <multiplier>null</multiplier> <offset>null</offset> -->
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>null</td>   <!-- memory variable again -->
         <td>v6</td>     <!-- v6 is the not in file but in congruence entry -->
         <td>null</td>   <!-- lowerbound and upperbound -->
         <td>[0,1]</td>  <!-- <multiplier>0</multiplier> <offset>1</offset> -->
    </tr>
</table>
```

Can any expert give the solution? i can't solve it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your input XML and expected output! Now please add your XSLT stylesheet. That way, we'll be able to see what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!-- index Entries by their Values -->
<xsl:key name="fields" match="FIELD/Entry" use="Variable" />
<xsl:key name="congruence" match="CONGRUENCES/Entry" use="Variable" />

<xsl:template match="SEGMEM">
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>MemoryVariable</th>
      <th>Variable</th>
      <th>Bounds</th>
      <th>Congruence</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//Entry" />
  </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Entry[parent::FIELD]">
  <!-- find matching conguruence entry -->
  <xsl:variable name="c" select="key('congruence', Variable)" />
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="MemoryVariable" /></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="Variable" /></td>
    <td><xsl:apply-templates select="offset" mode="bracket" /></td>
    <td>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$c"><xsl:apply-templates select="$c/Value" mode="bracket" /></xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>null</xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </td>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Entry[parent::CONGRUENCES]">
  <!-- only output this if there is no matching field entry -->
  <xsl:if test="not(key('fields', Variable))">
    <tr>
      <td>null</td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Variable" /></td>
      <td>null</td>
      <td><xsl:apply-templates select="Value" mode="bracket" /></td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="bracket">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('[', *[1], ',', *[2], ']')" />
</xsl:template>
```

gives you

```
<table border="1">
  <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
    <th>MemoryVariable</th>
    <th>Variable</th>
    <th>Bounds</th>
    <th>Congruence</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>x</td>
    <td>x(v9)</td>
    <td>[0,31]</td>
    <td>[1,0]</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>LE</td>
    <td>LE(v10)</td>
    <td>[0,0]</td>
    <td>null</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>null</td>
    <td>v6</td>
    <td>null</td>
    <td>[0,1]</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

See http://www.xmlplayground.com/P9YpKF